# Convert selectedTextRange UITextRange to NSRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrange, uitextrange

How can I convert a `UITextRange` object to an `NSRange`? I've seen plenty of SO posts about going the other direction but that's the opposite of what I need. I'm using the `UITextRange` `selectedTextRange` which is a property of a `UITextView`. It returns a `UITextRange` but I need a range.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
- (NSRange) selectedRangeInTextView:(UITextView*)textView
{
    UITextPosition* beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;

    UITextRange* selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange;
    UITextPosition* selectionStart = selectedRange.start;
    UITextPosition* selectionEnd = selectedRange.end;

    const NSInteger location = [textView offsetFromPosition:beginning toPosition:selectionStart];
    const NSInteger length = [textView offsetFromPosition:selectionStart toPosition:selectionEnd];

    return NSMakeRange(location, length);
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Here's a Swift extension based on the answer by Vitaly S.

```
extension UITextInput {
    var selectedRange: NSRange? {
        guard let range = self.selectedTextRange else { return nil }
        let location = offsetFromPosition(beginningOfDocument, toPosition: range.start)
        let length = offsetFromPosition(range.start, toPosition: range.end)
        return NSRange(location: location, length: length)
    }
}
```

Swift 4

```
extension UITextInput {
    var selectedRange: NSRange? {
        guard let range = selectedTextRange else { return nil }
        let location = offset(from: beginningOfDocument, to: range.start)
        let length = offset(from: range.start, to: range.end)
        return NSRange(location: location, length: length)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`UITextView` has a property

```
@property(nonatomic) NSRange selectedRange;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. There are valid reasons why you need to convert from `UITextRange` to `NSRange`.

Comment: Also, it doesn't exist in swift

Comment: Also, UITextField only has `selectedTextRange`, so you need convert to a simple `NSRange`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
extension UITextInput
{
    var selectedRange: NSRange?
    {
        if let selectedRange = self.selectedTextRange
        {
           return NSMakeRange(self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start),
                              self.offset(from: selectedRange.start,      to: selectedRange.end))
        }
        else
        {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will be cleaner if you begin with `guard let.. else { return nil }` instead of the way you've written it.