# using UITextPosition, get previous character from textInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I've been searching high and low and can't figure out how to do this.  Lets say I have a string like this:

```
NSString *string = @"&foo !foo";
```

What I'm trying to do is differentiate between the two foos (sounds funny haha) inside a text view.  When I click on one, I want to know which (& or !) comes before it.  Here's how I'm getting the word:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
UITextView *TV = (UITextView*)recognizer.view;
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:TV];
location.y += TV.contentOffset.y;
UITextPosition *tapPosition = [TV closestPositionToPoint:CGPointMake(location.x, location.y)];
UITextRange *textRange = [TV.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition 
    withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
NSString *tappedWord = [TV textInRange:textRange];
```

I can't figure out how to get the previous character. `TV.tokenizer` `UITextGranularityCharacter` only gets the closest letter, not the symbol.  Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check: [Convert selectedTextRange UITextRange to NSRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149767/convert-selectedtextrange-uitextrange-to-nsrange) to convert your `UITextRange` to a `NSRange` (that I'll call `selectedRange`).

Inspiring me with the previous answer to the linked question, you'd need to add this at the end of your code:

```
UITextPosition *beginning = TV.beginningOfDocument;
UITextPosition *selectionStart = textRange.start;
UITextPosition *selectionEnd = textRange.end;
NSInteger location = [TV offsetFromPosition:beginning toPosition:selectionStart];
NSInteger length = [TV offsetFromPosition:selectionStart toPosition:selectionEnd];
NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(location,lenght);
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(selectedRange.location-1,1) //Maybe need to check if selectedRange.location>0
NSString *yourCharString = [[TV text] substringWithRange:range];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I saw that post before.  Before I make the new NSRange, I have to convert my UITextRange into a NSRange?

Comment: Yes, you have to transform the `UITextRange` (I corrected the "NSTextRange") into a `NSRange`.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Even though I'm still confused about how to do it.  I have the position of the tap, do I still need to break it down to UITextPosition selectionStart and selectionEnd?

Comment: I edited my answer. You should just have to add my code at the end of yours.

Comment: Sorry that I made you post the entire answer :) Thanks again.  Just didn't know how to modify to fit my example

Comment: It's ok. I just had to paste the previous answer code a rename a few var. But as long as you understand and it works.