# UITextView get previous character - (i.e character before the cursor position) (iOS7)

Tags: ios7, uitextview, uitextposition, uitextrange

I can't work out how I can get the previous character that was entered. so in other words how can I get the character that is just before the cursor any where inside the UITextView.

```
NSInteger pos = [self.textInput offsetFromPosition:self.textInput.beginningOfDocument toPosition:textrange.start];

CGRect s = [self.textInput caretRectForPosition:self.textInput.selectedTextRange.start];

UITextRange *textrange = [self.textInput characterRangeAtPoint: s.origin];
```

Thanks,

Kind Regards,

Will

Comment: Could inspire you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607883/using-uitextposition-get-previous-character-from-textinrange/23608114#23608114 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks it is what I was looking for, I did see it before actually but was not 100% sure, I modified it slightly and its good.

```
    UITextPosition *beginning = self.textInput.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *selectionStart = self.textInput.selectedTextRange.start;
    UITextPosition *selectionEnd = self.textInput.selectedTextRange.end;
    NSInteger location = [self.textInput offsetFromPosition:beginning toPosition:selectionStart];
    NSInteger length = [self.textInput offsetFromPosition:selectionStart toPosition:selectionEnd];
    NSRange selectedRange = NSMakeRange(location,length);
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(selectedRange.location-1,1);

    NSString *lastChar = [textValue substringWithRange:range];
```