# Detect Tap On Image's Attached In NSAttributedString While UITextVIew Editing Is True

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I'm using Below method for detecting taps on image in `UITextView`.

```
`func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool`
```

This method only call when `textView.isEditable = false`.

So then i add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UITextView` and it calls when user tap on image inside `UITextView`. But that point i don't know how i can detect on which image user tap if there is more than one inside `UITextView`. I also get `UITextView` x and y location of tap but dont know how i can get text or if it is image from these point

```
let TapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDetected(sender:)))
TapGesture.delegate = self
textView.addGestureRecognizer(TapGesture)`
```

I also tried to add a view in `textView.addSubview`. But i also don't know how i can change its position if user want to type a text before or after this subview, like it behave same as `NSAttributedString Images` change its position accordingly text.

```
let imgRect : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [imgRect]
let spacerView : UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
spacerView.backgroundColor = .red
textView.addSubview(spacerView)
```

Can anyone please tell me how i can detect tap on image while editing is true. Or anyone know how i can add action(addTarget) on `NSAttributedString` image. I'v also checked iOS default `Notes` App and they are doing same thing as i need. The main reason behind this feature i want to add attach videos Thumbnails option in `UiTextView`, when user tap on video thumbnail while typing, video will automatically play in player. I'm attaching video that i recorded from my phone, This is my [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpn3mlo2guwbnvy/TextView.zip?dl=0).

**I need exact same functionality that is on Below Video**

[image].

Thanks

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        print("touchesBegan")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let TapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDetected(sender:)))
        TapGesture.delegate = self
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(TapGesture)

        let imgRect : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [imgRect]
        let spacerView : UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        spacerView.backgroundColor = .red
        textView.addSubview(spacerView)

        textView.attributedText.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "image", options: .new, context: nil)
        textView.attributedText.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "image", options: .initial, context: nil)
        textView.attributedText.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "image", options: .old, context: nil)
        textView.attributedText.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "image", options: .prior, context: nil)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {

        var attributedString :NSMutableAttributedString!
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:textView.attributedText)
        let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        textAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "taylor")
        let oldWidth = textAttachment.image!.size.width;

        //I'm subtracting 10px to make the image display nicely, accounting
        //for the padding inside the textView

        let scaleFactor = (oldWidth / (textView.frame.size.width - 10))
        textAttachment.image = UIImage(cgImage: textAttachment.image!.cgImage!, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: .up)
        let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
        attributedString.append(attrStringWithImage)
        textView.attributedText = attributedString;
    }

    @objc func tapDetected(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        print("Tap On Image")
        print("Tap Location",sender.location(in: sender.view))

        guard case let senderView = sender.view, (senderView is UITextView) else {
            return
        }

        // calculate layout manager touch location
        let textView = senderView as! UITextView, // we sure this is an UITextView, so force casting it
        layoutManager = textView.layoutManager

        var location = sender.location(in: textView)
        location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left
        location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top

        print("location",location)

        let textContainer = textView.textContainer,
        characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil),
        textStorage = textView.textStorage

        guard characterIndex < textStorage.length else {
            return
        }
    }


    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("textViewDidChange")
    }

    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        print("textViewShouldBeginEditing")
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("textViewDidBeginEditing")
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("textViewDidBeginEditing")
    }

    func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        print("textViewShouldEndEditing")
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("textViewDidChangeSelection")

        print("selectedText", textView.selectedRange.location)
        print("textView.attributedText.containsAttachments(in: textView.selectedRange",textView.attributedText.containsAttachments(in: textView.selectedRange))
        print("textView.attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: textView.selectedRange)",textView.attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: textView.selectedRange))

        let img = textView.getParts()
        for i in img {
            if let image = i as? UIImage {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("observeValueobserveValueobserveValueobserveValueobserveValue  keyPath \(String(describing: keyPath)) change \(String(describing: change)) context \(String(describing: context)) ")
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        print("textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String)")
        return true
    }


    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        print("textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool ")
        return true
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        print("textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool")
        imageView.image = textAttachment.image
        return true
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        print("textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool")
        return true
    }
}

extension UITextView {
    func getParts() -> [AnyObject] {
        var parts = [AnyObject]()

        let attributedString = self.attributedText
        let range = self.selectedRange//NSMakeRange(0, (attributedString?.length)!)
        attributedString?.enumerateAttributes(in: range, options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (object, range, stop) in
            if object.keys.contains(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment) {
                if let attachment = object[NSAttributedStringKey.attachment] as? NSTextAttachment {
                    if let image = attachment.image {
                        parts.append(image)
                    } else if let image = attachment.image(forBounds: attachment.bounds, textContainer: nil, characterIndex: range.location) {
                        parts.append(image)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                let stringValue : String = attributedString!.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                if (!stringValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty) {
                    parts.append(stringValue as AnyObject)
                }
            }
        }
        return parts
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this code works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607883/using-uitextposition-get-previous-character-from-textinrange/23608114#23608114 Then doing a substring could do the job and after enumerate the `NSAttributedStringKey.attachment` of that part?

Comment: @Larme I checked this but did't working as i need

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, create a new NSAttributedStringKey that you'll use to identify the image attachment. Then create an NSTextAttachment with the image, wrap it in a NSMutableAttributedString and add the custom attribute to it. Finally add the wrapper to the full NSAttributedString and attach a UITapGestureRecognizer.

Then when in the selector on the UITapGestureRecognizer simply look for that custom tag.

Code for most bits:

```
extension NSAttributedStringKey {
    static let imagePath = NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: "imagePath")
}
```

... then when setting up the text display

```
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString()    
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
imageAttachment.image = image

let imageAttributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString

let customAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.imagePath: imagePath ]
imageAttributedString.addAttributes(customAttribute, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: imageAttributedString.length))
            
fullString.append(imageAttributedString)
```

then in the function called by the tap action:

```
    @objc func onImageTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      let textView = sender.view as! UITextView
      let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager
    
      // location of tap in textView coordinates
      var location = sender.location(in: textView)
      location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left;
      location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top;
    
      // character index at tap location
      let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
    
      // if index is valid 
      if characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length {

        // check if the tap location has the custom attribute
        let attributeValue = textView.attributedText.attribute(NSAttributedStringKey.imagePath, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? String
        if let value = attributeValue {
            print("You tapped on \(NSAttributedStringKey.imagePath) and the value is: \(value)")
        }
        
    }

}
```

From there you know the tap was in the image and you have the coordinates inside the image frame, so you can use that combination to figure out where in the image was tapped.

Comment: What's the value of customAttribute

Answer (score 3):

As Charles's answer is great hint, I would like to shard my approaching.

My way is not much different from him, instead to add a new attribute key, I am using the original "attachment" as my key to get the image.

So, create an image array, update the array every time you add / remove image(s) (to make sure the right order of images).

Create an image viewer for view images (you can search from internet).

Use Charles answer, to detect the tap on image (I use "attachment" key instead of custom key).

Once the tap on an image, open image viewer and show the current image, you should parse the image array to image viewer, so the image viewer can display image in the right order.

Here is a snip of my code:

```
@objc func tapOnImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let textView = sender.view as! UITextView
    let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager

    var location = sender.location(in: textView)
    location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= memtextViewoView.textContainerInset.top

    let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location,
                                                      in: textView.textContainer,
                                                      fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    if characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length {    
        let attachment = textView.attributedText.attribute(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment,
                                                         at: characterIndex,
                                                         effectiveRange: nil) as? NSTextAttachment
        if let attachImage = attachment {
            print("tap on image: ", attachImage.image)

        }
    }
}
```

From above code, you can found when you click on different image, the console will show different object, from there you can use the image do whatever you need.

I hope this can help people who stuck on this kind of question.

By the way, I'm using swift 4.1 on xcode 9.2